# How to remove width and height attributes from multiple posts in Wordpress (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress, phpmyadmin

So I have thousands of Wordpress posts with the width and height attributes which I want to remove. For example:

```
img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-21011999" title="sometitle" 
alt="somealt" src="http://mysite.com/blabla/somefile.jpg" width="xxx" height="xxx"
```

As i mentioned i want to remove `width="xxx" height="xxx"` and i want to remove them directly from MySQL, dont want to use any PHP functions or similar.

Is there a query i can run through PhpMyadmin?

Are there any regex i can use for the xxx which is different for each post.

Thank you!

Comment: cant you delete them manually from this file?just go to this file where u have width and heigth and remove them

Comment: No because there are tousands of posts so i would need to spend few days for this.

Comment: i mean its just one file who generates those imgaes ,

Comment: Are width and height always 3 digits?

Comment: @goodmood Unfortunately no, that is not how Wordpress functionate. I can remove the height and width attributes for the future posts, but i need a way to remove them from the old posts.

Comment: @speakr not always 3 digits, they are 2, 3 or 4 digits. But i can run 3 different queries if that can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small PHP script (outside of WordPress of course) that will accomplish this quite easily using Regex.

```
<?php

$host = "hostname";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$db   = "database";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

$pattern = "/width|height=\"[0-9]*\"/";

$query = "SELECT ID, post_content FROM wp_posts";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $row['post_content']))
    {
        $row['post_content'] = preg_replace($pattern, "", $row['post_content']);
        mysql_query("UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=" . $row['post_content'] . "WHERE ID=" . $row['ID'];
    }
}

?>
```

That's the way I'd do it anyway. I'm assuming when you said "no PHP functions" that you mean that you want the data permanently updated in the database, rather than just updated on the fly every time the page is loaded. This should solve the issue. Writing a raw SQL query to deal with this problem will likely be much more complicated.

You don't need to do this within WordPress. You could even run this on a different host, provided said host has database access.

Note: I haven't tested any of this. If you use it, I'd make sure to run it on a small subsection of your database before applying it sitewide.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this script and it has some errors. I have corrected them and used it. It works. Make sure the table name (wpfs_posts) correspondents to your table name with posts. Always have a backup off course.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "nameuser";
$pass = "password";
$db   = "namedb";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

$pattern = "/width|height=\"[0-9]*\"/";

$query = "SELECT ID, post_content FROM wpfs_posts";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $row['post_content']))
    {
        $row['post_content'] = preg_replace($pattern, "", $row['post_content']);
        $row['post_content']=mysql_real_escape_string($row['post_content']);
        mysql_query("UPDATE wpfs_posts SET post_content='" . $row['post_content'] . "' WHERE ID=" . $row['ID']);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Above code still has issue, when run by me it cause width value not removed but work for height. so i changed the pattern to **$pattern = "/width=\"[0-9]*\"|height=\"[0-9]*\"/";**  now it works for both width and height